# Constructor calling itself

Tags: java, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have recently found out that no argument constructor and multiple argument constructor cannnot call each other in turns. What is the underlying reason of this limitation? Some might say that constructors are where resources are initialised. So they must not be called recursively. I want to know if this is the only reason or not. Functions/methods/procedures can be called recursively. Why not constructors?

Comment: Having a constructor call itself is effectively creating an infinite loop with no exit.

Comment: Not really. Assuming you add that recusive step in a catch clause, that wouldn't cause an inifinite loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in the fact that the call to another constructor is the first line of any constructor and hence your if condition to break out of recursion will never be executed and hence stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The main purpose of the constructor is to initialize all the global variables described in a particular class.

```
For Example: 

public class Addition(){

int value1;
int value2;

   public Addition(){ // default constructor
       a=10;
       b=10;
   }

  public Addition(int a, int b){
      this(); // constructors having parameters , overloaded constructor
      value1=a;
      value2=b;
  }
}

public class Main(){
  public static void main(){
     Addition addition = new Addition(); //or
     Addition addition = new Addition(15,15);  
  }
}
```

Here, if you want to make instance of the class you can either make instance by calling default constructor or by calling constructor having parameters. So the constructors are overloaded and not overridden. If you want to call another constructor, that can only be done be putting either `this()` or `super()` in the first line of the constructor. But this is not prefferable.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not intended to be called explicitly outside object initialization, because it's restricted in most (I guess all) languages. Instead, you can create an additional `protected Init(...)` member function and call it inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement that constructor cannot call other constructors are not true for every programming languages. At least I know Java can do this, while C++ cannot. But you could easily overcome this limitation by writing a private __init function and let all your constructors call it.

Comment: I meant recursively calling each other in turns. I think Java would give this compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

In all languages you've listed objects contain finite (and normally short) set of properties. Each property could contain recursive structure (i.e. list), but it still represented by a single property in the object.

I don't see need to recursively call constructors. It feels like a strange use recursion to initialize several well know properties.

As you've said you can call constructors in non-recursive way to share code in some languages you've mentioned.

C#: [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
public Employee(int weeklySalary, int numberOfWeeks)
    : this(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)
{
}
```