# Recursive Constructor Invocation

Tags: java, recursion, constructor, this

```
public class LecturerInfo extends StaffInfo {

    private float salary;

    public LecturerInfo()
    {
        this();
        this.Name = null;
        this.Address = null;
        this.salary=(float) 0.0;
    }

    public LecturerInfo(String nama, String alamat, float gaji)
    {
        super(nama, alamat);
        Name = nama;
        Address = alamat;
        salary = gaji;
    }

    @Override
    public void displayInfo()
    {
         System.out.println("Name :" +Name);
         System.out.println("Address :" +Address);
         System.out.println("Salary :" +salary);
    }
}
```

This code shows an error which is:

> Recursive constructor invocation LecturerInfo()

Is it because of the no-argument constructor having conflicts with the constructor with parameters?

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: Hopefully, he will lose marks for bad style.  That will get his attention.  But a savage code review in the workplace would be effective too ... if he makes it past the obligatory interview coding exercise.

Comment: Why not version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918795/constructor-calling-itself

Answer (score 14):

the code below is recursive. Since `this()` will call no arg constructor of current class that means `LectureInfo()` again.

```
public LecturerInfo()
{
    this(); //here it translates to LectureInfo() 
    this.Name = null;
    this.Address = null;
    this.salary=(float) 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

by calling `this()` you are calling your own constructor. By observing your code it seems you were supposed to call `super()` instead of `this();`

Comment: The default `super()` constructor is automatically called if no other super constructor is called specifically. No need to add this line...

Comment: It's also quite possible that he meant to call `this(null, null, 0.0f);`

Answer (score 2):

if you modify the fist constructor to this:

```
 public LecturerInfo()
 {
   this(null, null, (float)0.0);
 }
```

this will be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
    public LecturerInfo()
          {
              this(); //Here you're invoking the default constructor inside default constructor, which is constructor recursion, which is not allowed.  
              this.Name = null;
              this.Address = null;
              this.salary=(float) 0.0;
          }
```

try this:
Invoking parameterized constructor inside default constructor.

```
    public LecturerInfo()
          {
              this("null","null",0.0f);
          }
```