# Recursive constructor invocation error can't find solution

Tags: java, recursion, constructor, this, invocation

I get the recursive construct overflow invocation error at the four public tuna parts (parts=maybe a class or something else?). It worked on the tutorial but not for me and can't seem to see where

```
public class tuna {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    public tuna() {
        this(0,0,0); //default  
    }
    public tuna(int h){
        this(h,0,0);    //with hours input
    }
    public tuna(int h, int m){
        this(h,m,0);    //with hours and minutes
    }
    public tuna(int h, int m, int s){
        this(h,m,s);    //with hours, minutes and seconds
    }
```

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458819/recursive-constructor-invocation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing a recursive call here:

```
public tuna(int h, int m, int s){
    this(h,m,s);    //with hours, minutes and seconds
}
```

You should set your private members in this constructor. It should be something like:

```
public tuna(int h, int m, int s){
    this.h = h;    //with hours, minutes and seconds
    this.m = m;
    this.s = s;
}
```

Comment: sorry im working on java. so if i change that how should i output it for the this(0,0,0) since it has no variables?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't get you right, but you just have to change the tuna(int h, int m, int s) constructor as I said. Everything else should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

```
public tuna(int h, int m, int s){
    this(h,m,s);    //with hours, minutes and seconds
}
```

Insead of this(h,m,s); use setTime(h,m,s);

It should be:

```
public class tuna {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    public tuna() {
        this(0,0,0); //default  
    }
    public tuna(int h){
        this(h,0,0);    //with hours input
    }
    public tuna(int h, int m){
        this(h,m,0);    //with hours and minutes
    }
    public tuna(int h, int m, int s){
        setTime(h,m,s);    //with hours, minutes and seconds
    }  
   // define setTime method below
```

Comment: Your answer doen't add any information to already accepted one. Please avoid spamming duplicate answers